# How can I see individual calls I've made to a Google API?

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

Is it possible to see a list of calls that I've made to one of the Google APIs?

I saw there is an [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive%20https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list) but I think this only works for enterprise accounts.

Answer (score 2):

No you cant see which calls you have sent to google

The best you can see is something in Google Developer console

[image]

All it really shows is what methods for the api you are calling now what what parameters you have been sending to each call.